# Deploying a Maven Project using Vaadin to Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, maven, vaadin

This may be an incredibly stupid question, but I have a web application that relies heavily on jQuery for many various widgets and aesthetic utilities that I'm trying to migrate into using Vaadin. For starters, I'm attempting to just create your run-of-the-mill "Hello World" application -- built with Maven and deployed to Tomcat -- with Vaadin, and I'm having a problem deploying it. I've been following the turtorial posted here ( https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/intro.walkthrough.html ). Here's my file structure thus far:

```
HelloWorld
    src
        main
            java
                com
                    business
                        helloworld
                            HelloWorld.java
            resources
            webapp
                WEB-INF
                    web.xml
        test
    target
    pom.xml
```

I'm guessing that my problem lies somewhere in my `web.xml` that follows:

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>HelloWorld</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've tried my best to follow the examples I've seen, but I have a feeling I'm making a stupid mistake. When I run the project as a Maven Build (tomcat:redeploy), it doesn't appear in my Tomcat Manager. Any ideas? If you need any more information (like what's in my pom.xml), just let me know...

EDIT: Is it better to create a Vaadin Project and convert it to Maven, or vis versa?

Comment: Check the [steps](http://centurion.dynalias.com/w/software/maven#how_to_deploy_to_remote_tomcat) I've made for myself: is Tomcat manager application running? Are all credentials defined correctly? What is the plugin output (does it report success)?

Comment: can you get your maven project to emit a war file, then copy that war to tomcat and have it work?  At least then you'll know if it's your war or your deploy step.

Comment: Tomcat has been working just fine for all of my projects, Maven or otherwise, though when I go to deploy the Vaadin project, nothing shows up in the Tomcat console like I'd hope. I'll try generating a war and deploying that specifically, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyApplicationClass` in application param-value should be the whole qualified class name, like

> com.business.helloworld.HelloWorld

(I'm on a mobile phone so I didn't check the syntax, but that should be it.)

Edit: To the second question, there's an Maven archetype that creates an Maven `Vaadin` project. By using that you won't have to convert either way.

Comment: I'd say that com.business.helloworld.HelloWorld is enough, since src/main/java is just a part of the structure of a Maven project.

Comment: True. I just read and wrote the whole structure without actually thinking about it. The package name declared in the java name is the part that is missing however.